# div img(svg) stretched to viewport height and width

Tags: html, css, svg, viewport, stretch

I am trying to fill the image (.svg) width to my DIV allowing it to stretch but my image only goes 100% width and with height it crops the bottom part.

How can i make it stretch height to viewport height?
I already tried to make the image into a background image but this doesn't work in the design.

```css
.flag {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 background-size: contain;
}
#flag img{
 width: 100vh;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="cover" style="min-height: 100vh">
 <img src="img/background.svg" class="flag"></div> 
</section>
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px"
  height="768px" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 768" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_1" display="none">
 <rect x="-0.5" y="0.5" display="inline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="57" height="768"/>
 <rect x="967.5" y="0.5" display="inline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="57" height="768"/>
 <rect x="-0.5" y="0.5" display="inline" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1025" height="57"/>
 <rect x="-0.5" y="711.5" display="inline" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1025" height="57"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
 <rect fill="#FFFFFF" width="1024" height="768"/>
 <rect y="103" width="1022" height="34"/>
 <rect y="171" width="1022" height="34"/>
 <rect y="239" width="1022" height="34"/>
 <rect y="631" width="1022" height="34"/>
 <rect y="563" width="1022" height="34"/>
 <rect y="495" width="1022" height="34"/>
 <rect x="55" y="58" fill="#E5452D" width="912" height="654"/>
 <rect x="55" y="385" fill="#0698CF" width="912" height="327"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please post the `svg` code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stretch the image according to the view port you will have to:

1. Change `svg`'s `width` and `height` to `100%` and add `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.
2. Since you are using the `img` tag and this only works if `width` or `height` is a fixed value, you will have to use JavaScript to set the `img`'s `width` or `height` using JavaScript.

Here is an example.

**Note**: In your case, you will have to set the `img`'s `height`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzrr7qkn/)**

```js
var d = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

function resize() {
  d.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
}
resize();
window.onresize = resize;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 768" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <g id="Layer_1" display="none">
      <rect x="-0.5" y="0.5" display="inline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="57" height="768" />
      <rect x="967.5" y="0.5" display="inline" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="57" height="768" />
      <rect x="-0.5" y="0.5" display="inline" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1025" height="57" />
      <rect x="-0.5" y="711.5" display="inline" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1025" height="57" />
    </g>
    <g id="Layer_2">
      <rect fill="#FFFFFF" width="1024" height="768" />
      <rect y="103" width="1022" height="34" />
      <rect y="171" width="1022" height="34" />
      <rect y="239" width="1022" height="34" />
      <rect y="631" width="1022" height="34" />
      <rect y="563" width="1022" height="34" />
      <rect y="495" width="1022" height="34" />
      <rect x="55" y="58" fill="#E5452D" width="912" height="654" />
      <rect x="55" y="385" fill="#0698CF" width="912" height="327" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the .svg file, the first one i need to add to my .js and the second one to my .css? I'm not very known to js.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you maybe show it to me in jsfiddle? I get totally lost with the code snippet here

Comment: I only use position, no float.
Edit: Yes, only one element with flag

Comment: @Marcel - Here you go ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzrr7qkn/). I've encoded the `svg` code in my answer to base64 and used it as `img`'s `src`.

Answer (score 1):

In browsers that support it you can turn the viewBox of the image off using [an SVG fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers). Firefox supports viewBox none (from the SVG 1.2 tiny specification) Getting rid of the viewBox will allow the image to be displayed without forcing an aspect ratio.

The other alternative would be to set preserveAspectRatio to none (again a fragment identifier can do this) i.e.  #svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none)) depending on exactly what you want.

You can do both if you need to. I've shown preserveAspectRatio below.

```html
<section class="cover" style="min-height: 100vh">
    <img src="http://www.klh-dev.com/lehava/train/test.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))" class="flag">
</section>
```

Comment: I'm confused, the OP wants to stretch the background according to the view port. Btw, +1 for the fragment identifier.

Answer (score 0):

use this as your css file:

```
.flag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: contain;
}

img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwnkswpo/

**I will improve my answer soon**

Comment: You have a <\div> tag after your image. What is that?

Comment: Silly mistake. Removed it, stretching error stays the same.

Comment: I actually have no clue.. Its working on my pc. Make sure you uploaded and saved the correct file

Comment: There is no way  this will work without making some changes to the `svg` file itself.

Comment: Tried to open it with chrome and safari but doesn't show difference. Though working on a mac...

What edits do you suggest to make to the svg to make it work?

Comment: Actually @chipChocolate.py  you can do this without changing the image (assuming the UA supports it) see my answer.